# Draw a flowchart of a simple payroll system that will display an employee’s information

Tags: graphs

Ask for the name of the employee.

- If the employee is full time, get his monthly salary rate. Then, display his name and salary.
- If the employee is part time, get his rate per hour and the total number of hours he worked
  for the entire month. Then, display his name and wage.

Hello guys, I am freshman in college and I've been trying my best to think of a flowchart display that could potentially answer this question. Our professor was a newly hired and we were behind our topics. We were not given many examples and of course I had to look ones for myself and while I do get the idea, I can't seem to write it down myself. Please help.